# Applying QM to a red laser

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, experimental-physics

I want to see if and how can the Heisenberg inequality be demonstrated in real life. For this I consider a laser beam aimed at a very small slit, for example two razor blade close to each other.

In Quantum mechanics, we can derive the Heisenberg inequality using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, this is sometimes stated as
$$
\sigma_x \sigma_p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2} \tag{1}
$$
with $\sigma_a = \sqrt{\left<a\right>^2 -\left< a^2 \right>} $, $\left<a\right> = \left<\psi|\hat{a}|\psi\right>$ for some state $\psi$ and with $\hbar$ begin the reduced Planck constant.

Now I assume that the light comes out of the laser in terms of Gaussian wave packets

$$
f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-x_0}{\sigma_x}\right)^2}e^{i kx}
$$
with $x_0$ and $k = 2 \pi/\lambda$ being constants, for such a wave packet the relation (1) reduces to equality.

Now I wanted to crank some numbers into the relation (1) to see how close would I have to put the two razor blades to each other, to reduce $\sigma_x$ and in turn increase $\sigma_p$. But I'm having real trouble relating the $\sigma_x$ quantity to the actual width of the hole. How do I do this? Furthermore is the would the assumption of light travelling as light packets from laser be somewhat accurate?

Comment: [The classical version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction) works just fine for light.  Plane waves work just fine, here.  You don't need the wave-packet.  It's irrelevant baggage in this problem, because the spreading will occur perpendicular to the $x$ direction (direction of propagation) anyway. The slits will be in the $y$-$z$ plane, and the spreading will happen in that plane, not along the direction of motion.

Comment: That's very much what i thought, but I've seen (from non-reputable sources) that this set-up is proof of the Heisenberg principle and I wanted to check if the scales can be anywhere near the quantum mechanic relevant scale...

Comment: Heisenberg's uncertainty principle is a general mathematical lemma about certain types of operators that appear in the mathematics of linear wave equations. It has absolutely nothing to do with quantum mechanics. You WIFI-router has an algorithm that uses it to shape the frequency spectrum of its signals, for instance. You would encounter it in the analysis of music if you were interested in the question how one can reconstruct the time at which the piano player hit the key from the actual audio recording of the piano etc..